# Unable to install Commerce Server-- silent installation

Tags: sitecore-commerce, installation

I am trying to install Commerce Server in silent mode using this command:

`setup.exe /l %systemdrive%\install.log /ADDLOCAL ALL /PRODUCT CommerceServer /passive /norestart`

based on [this MSDN link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa544794(v=cs.70).aspx).

But after installation, a configuration popup is opening which I am trying to suppress. Could someone help me either to suppress the pop up or provide `csconfig.xml` as input to the `csconfig.exe` immediately after installation.

This is the popup I want to supress:

[image]

I have also tried giving xml as source to configure but with no luck. Below is the command I used and source link:

`"commerceserver.exe "-silent [CSCONFIGXML=CSConfig.xml] [NOCSCONFIG] [NOSTAGING]`

http://commercesdn.sitecore.net/SCpbCS81/SitecoreCommerceDeploymentGuide/en-us/c_CommerceServerInstaller.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To provide the detailed explanation, here is how we can run it.

This install exe supports the following switches and flags

switches

- log:`<filename>`  log file to use
- quiet -silent     unattended install (requires flag CSCONFIGXML)
- passive           unattended install with progress bar

flags

- CSCONFIGXML=      file to use for CSConfig
- INSTALLDIR=                   32bit path for installing files
- INSTALLDIR64=              64 bit path for installing files

We have used the CSConfig.xml file with following content (you need to update with your details) to install silently to the default locations and using the default log file.

```
 <Configuration>
  <SQL ID="CommerceAdminDB">
    <Server>LT-ROHIT</Server>
    <Database>MSCS_Admin</Database>
    <WindowsSecurity>no</WindowsSecurity>
    <UserName>sa</UserName>
    <Password>******</Password>
  </SQL>
  <VirtualDirectory ID="Publishing" Create="True" />
  <NTService ID="StagingService">
    <UserName>rchopra</UserName>
    <Domain>domain\rchopra</Domain>
    <Password>*****</Password>
  </NTService>
</Configuration>
```

We have run following command to install silently. It worked fine without any issue.

```
CommerceServer-11.2.189.0.exe -silent CSCONFIGXML="c:\CSConfig.xml"
```

I hope this helps.